# pyparsing -- extending fourFn.py example with function

Tags: python, pyparsing

The **fourFn.py** example from pyparsing has a dictionary where all the supported functions are listed.  I'm trying to add a definition to call the statistics mean function:

```py
fn = {
    "sin": math.sin,
    "cos": math.cos,
    "tan": math.tan,
    "exp": math.exp,
    "abs": abs,
    # added function, mean imported from statistics 
    "mean": mean,
    "trunc": lambda a: int(a),
    "round": round,
    "sgn": lambda a: -1 if a < -epsilon else 1 if a > epsilon else 0,
}
```

The mean function takes an iterable object as its argument, but apparently the grammar needs to be extended to recognize a list literal.  When I try to test it:

`test("mean([2, 5, 6])", mean([2, 5, 6]))`

I get the following error:

```sh
mean([2, 5, 6]) failed eval: Expected {{{{{{{{W:(ABCD..., ABCD...)
Suppress:("(") -} Group:(Group:(Forward: None) [, Group:(Forward:
None)]...)} Suppress:(")")} | "PI"} | "E"} | Re:('[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:
[eE][+-]?\\d+)?')} | W:(ABCD..., ABCD...)} | Group:({{Suppress:("(") :
...} Suppress:(")")})}, found '['  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6) []
```

I've tried adding a grammar definition for a list:

`nlist = "[" + delimitedList(Group(expr)) + "]"`

And modified the fn_call defintion:

```py
fn_call = (ident + lpar - Group(expr_list | nlist) + rpar).setParseAction(
   lambda t: t.insert(0, (t.pop(0), len(t[0])))
)
```

This only returns this error:

```sh
mean([2, 5, 6]) failed eval: pop from empty list ['2', '5', '6', ('mean', 5)]
```

So, I guess I don't have the nlist definition quite right. Any suggestions on how I might get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Untested, but try `LBRACK, RBRACK = map(Suppress, "[]"); nlist = Group(LBRACK + delimitedList(expr) + RBRACK)`. You were grouping inside the delimitedList, you really want to group the entire list. Then instead of adding nlist to the definition of fn_call, add it as another alternative for atom: (`(fn_call | pi | e | fnumber | ident | nlist)`). This should allow you to write things like "[1,2,3] * 3".

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  These changes end up causing a similar error:

```mean([2, 5, 6]) failed eval: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not ParseResults ['2', '5', '6', (['2', '5', '6'], {}), ('mean', 1)]```

FWIW, the first exception is generated at line 2883 in ```class _SingleCharLiteral(Literal)``` in the parseImpl() method.  It apparently wants to see a "+" character but does not since instring[loc] is the 1st char of "mean".   

OTOH, at least it now correctly determines that mean accepts 1 argument. :-)